# Iterating through a javascript object to get key-value pairs

Tags: javascript, json, loops, undefined, key-value

Here's my code:

```
obj = {"TIME":123,"DATE":456}

console.log(obj.TIME);
console.log("---------")

for (var key in obj) {
  console.log(key);
  console.log(obj.key);
}
```

It prints as the following:

```
123
---------
TIME
undefined
DATE
undefined
```

Why does console.log(obj.key) print as undefined?

I want my code to print out the following, using obj.key to print out the value for each key:

```
123
---------
TIME
123
DATE
456
```

How do I do so?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

because there is no key in the object with the name 'key'. `obj.key` means you are trying to access a key inside obj with the name key. `obj.key` is same as `obj['key']`

you need to use `obj[key]`, like this:

```js
obj = {"TIME":123,"DATE":456}

console.log(obj.TIME);
console.log("---------")

for (var key in obj) {
  console.log(key);
  console.log(obj[key]);
}
```